# Where is the .SNK file created too?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, msdn

I'm attempting to follow [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736/) guide on the MSDN website. However I'm having trouble with step 13:

> 13. Copy the MyKeyFile.SNK file to your project folder.

Potentially the stupidest question ever asked, but: From Where?!

Thank You!

Comment: BTW, I'm using VS 2013 Pro (I assumed this wouldn't have an effect, however I think I was wrong about that!)

Comment: Step 12.a: type `cd \where\your\project\is\stored`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 12:

> To create a strong name for your class library, type the following command at the Visual Studio .NET command prompt:
>   sn.exe -k MyKeyFile.SNK

The file will be created in the current directory of the command window.

Comment: It appears it wouldn't create it (Posted back as success) when I left the command window in the root directory. Cheers anyway!